Finite difference for heat conduction equation - oscillation in second derivative calc
I am solving 1D heat conduction equation with,
dt = 1sec, dx = 0.001 m and total 10 nodes with fixed temp at both ends.
For value of K >1.2, the solution becomes unstable.
For k = 1 (temp and second derivative approximation)


For k = 1.15 (temp and second derivative)


The oscillation keeps on increasing in magnitude with increase in k value.
What error is this? and how to resolve this?

So, first question: is this a physical problem that happens in heat transfer in a pipe or block? Send question: if not, then check the maths.

Have you tried smaller time steps, and more - but smaller - elements?

You have discovered numerical instability.  As Mark suggested, vary time step size and element size until results stop changing.

Hi,
I played around with the time step and was able to get rid off the oscillations.
